# Issue with website displaying in Internet Explorer

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, elementor

I am having an issue with my WordPress site designed with the Elementor plugin and Ocean WP theme. It displays perfectly fine in Chrome, Firefox and Edge. However, it doesn’t display at all on Internet Explorer 11 – only one picture is visible and headers/footers etc don't display.

I’ve tried to look at plugins etc but can’t find the reason for it. Can anyone please suggest some solutions? I have also tried to look at the code but can't see what is causing it to break when attempting to display in Internet Explorer 11.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Have you tried [the Troubleshooting Guides](https://codex.wordpress.org/Troubleshooting) from the Codex?

Comment: Thanks - I have tried this with no success unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Your site is showing several errors in the console of the IE 11 browser.

[image]

The issue can be caused by the WP theme or Elementor plugin.

It can be possible that one of these 2 things using any modern features that are not supported in the IE 11 browser.

I found the below information on the [Wordpress browser issues](https://wordpress.com/support/browser-issues/) page.

> Internet Explorer: Due to browser incompatibility, some themes are not
>   fully functional in Internet Explorer 10 or earlier. If you are using
>   Internet Explorer 10 or below we recommend upgrading your browser for
>   an optimal experience.

I found the below information on the [Elementor requirements](https://docs.elementor.com/article/38-requirements) page.

> Most features will display properly in IE but because IE is an older
>   browser, it is incapable of supporting some of the modern web
>   technologies that Elementor may utilize for some of its features.

Below are the links for the support pages of the Elementor and Wordpress. You can also try to know their opinion on this issue. It may help you to narrow down the issue.

1. [Wordpress support](https://wordpress.com/support/contact/)
2. [Elementor support](https://elementor.com/contact/)

Comment: Thanks for that - much appreciated. The website used to work on IE 11 until a month ago so I am trying to find out why the Console is showing 3 errors. The same Console in Edge shows no errors. Any idea why that might be happening? What is different between these two browsers?

Comment: It's a completely different browser engine under the hood. You should not compare IE11 to Edge for that reason. And probably IE11 support is not great after all, see the [System Requirements for Elementor](https://docs.elementor.com/article/38-requirements)

Comment: I suggest you try to check whether anything got updated or modified in this site within a month. It may help you to find the cause of this issue. It may help to narrow down the issue.